# Slow loading of an icecast2 flux with QMediaPlayer in Qt5

Tags: performance, qt, qt5, icecast, qmediaplayer

I have a project for school: i have to play an Icecast2 audio flux (http://campus.abeille.com:8000/campus) with Qt5 application. That why, i wrote this code :

```
QUrl url("http://campus.abeille.com:8000/campus");

player->setMedia(url);
player->setVolume(50);
player->play();
```

I specify that "player" is a QMediaPlayer object. My issue is that this flux takes about 5 min to load after lauching the "play" command ! With other flux there is no (or little) delay (for example only 3sec for that one : http://listen.42fm.ru:8000/stealkill).

What have i missed ? Is there a specific way to deal correctly with Icecast2 flux with Qt ? Is it a configuration error on Icecast2 server side ?

Your help would be very apreciated!

Comment: The immediate difference between both is that the "working" stream is served by an up to date version of Icecast (2.4.2), while "your" stream is served by a very old version (2.3.2). Also "your" stream blatantly lies about the bitrate: 64kbit/s claimed vs. 248kbit/s actual. If this is the cause, I don't know. Would need deeper investigation, e.g. testing with other streams to find a common denominator. One thing you should check is if you can influence the buffer size.

Comment: Thanks for your advices! I will check all the clues you gave to me.

Comment: I am still stuck onto this problem and i just seen the comment of TBR ! Can you be more explicit with your "%s/flux/stream/g" response TBR ?

Comment: What I meant is that the proper translation for "flux" is *stream*. That comment indicated that the word "flux" should be replaced everywhere in your question with the word "stream" to make it easier to understand.